# Are speculations about history on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions that ask “what would the world be if X had (not) happened” on-topic for this site? What about the closely related “what would need to have changed for X to become true”?

Example:

- [Reasons why Electronics might not exist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/reasons-why-electronics-might-not-exist)

Note that this is not about discussing [specific alternate history works](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/are-questions-about-alternate-history-on-or-off-topic).

This is close to [Sci-fi technology: On topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/sci-fi-technology-on-topic), but there may be good reasons to allow the one and not the other.

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

We're not so much a site for Q&A about science fiction & fantasy, as about existing works of science fiction and fantasy.  (If the question is about creating a new work, then we're redirecting them to writers).

If the question is about a general scientific or fantastic idea, unconnected to any existing work, then it's off-topic.

Comment: In general I like keeping as open a possible (and simply controlling bad *questions*, not bad *topics*), but this is too wide even for me.  If this was ok, where would be the limit?